# Laravel Cache, variable inside closure undefined?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a function like this:

```
public function entity($entity_id, Request $request)
{
    $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);
    $entity = Cache::remember('entities', $expiresAt, function () {
        return Entity::where('id', $entity_id)
            ->with('address')
            ->with('_geoloc')
            ->first();
    });
```

However this returns an error saying, $entity_id is undefined, however when I do dd($entity_id) after $expiresAt, it is defined as I get the id back, id comes from url if that is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should allow anonymous function to capture the variable outside the scope. `$entity_id` its outside the scope. This is how php express the closure. With a `use()` would work.

```
public function entity($entity_id, Request $request)
{
$expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);
$entity = Cache::remember('entities', $expiresAt, function () use($entity_id) {
    return Entity::where('id', $entity_id)
        ->with('address')
        ->with('_geoloc')
        ->first();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, will accept this once I can, +1 for explaining in a bit more details

Comment: Thank you :) I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `use($entity_id)` because that variable is outside the scope of the annonymous function it needs to be passed in using the use keyword as shown in the example below :

```
public function entity($entity_id, Request $request)
{
    $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);
    $entity = Cache::remember('entities', $expiresAt, function ()use($entity_id) {
        return Entity::where('id', $entity_id)
            ->with('address')
            ->with('_geoloc')
            ->first();
    });
```